# combining strings and returning - javascript

Tags: javascript, function, return

```
<html>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function concatStrings(){
      var string1 = "programming";
      var string2 = "class";
      var sentence = string1 + " " + string2;
      return sentence
    } 
</script>
</html>
```

I am new to JavaScript and was wondering how to get a simple statement to return. I tried this and tested it but nothing had shown up. What should I do to have the variable, sentence, to show up?

Comment: you have to print/display it.

Comment: Where do you want it to show?

Comment: You are correctly defining the function however you are not calling it at the moment. You can try in the firebug console [on firefox] or in Chrome console: alert(concatStrings()); .

Comment: You just define a function. That itself does nothing. You have to call it somewhere and do output, e.g., using `console.log()` or `alert()`.

Comment: `console.log(concatStrings());`

Comment: To show in console `console.log(concatStrings())`; to show on page `document.body.innerHTML = concatStrings()`

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function concatStrings(){
      var string1 = "programming";
      var string2 = "class";
      var sentence = string1 + " " + string2;
      return sentence
    } 
    alert(concatStrings()); // Add this line to get a popup
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `alert(sentence);` or `console.log(sentence);` instead of `return sentence`. alert() will display the string in an alert message box where as console.log will log the string in the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

Try alert() or console

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        function concatStrings(){
          var string1 = "programming";
          var string2 = "class";
          var sentence = string1 + " " + string2;
          return sentence
        } 
    //Try alert
    alert(concatStrings());

    // OR Console
    console.log(concatStrings());
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

Right now your `concatStrings()` function is returning the value, but isn't doing what you expect it to. Technically speaking, the code is correct-- so you're encountering a logic error.

Unfortunately, you are not actually pushing the string onto the page. JQuery is an excellent tool to use. However, without utilizing the JQuery library, the simplest option here is to use Javascript's built-in DOM handling functions. Notably, `getElementById()`:

```
<html>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
            concatStrings();
        });
        function concatStrings(){
            var string1 = "programming";
            var string2 = "class";
            var sentence = string1 + " " + string2;
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = sentence;
         } 
     </script>
<div id="content">

    </div>
    </html>
```

In this manner, you can populate the contents of DOM elements within the page using Javascript.

Please notice `document.getElementById("content").innerHTML)`, this allows you to search through the existing page `document`, find a given element (in this case, a `div` element with the id of `content`) and rewrite its contents with your desired string.

By using the aforementioned line, you'll see your string appear on the page **without** an alert popup or console log.